# Revit Extensions vs Plugins

Tags: revit

What is the difference between extensions and plug-ins?  I've been writing many plug-ins, and while diffing througg the SDK folder I came across the REX framework and extensions, but im not really clear on what the benifets of one over the other are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REX framework and extensions are Revit structure specific and built on top of pure simple Revit API add-ins:

- [The REX SDK](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/04/the-rex-sdk.html)
- [REX content generator](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/rex-content-generator.html)
- [Structural Analytical Code Checking and Results Builder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/06/structural-analytical-code-checking-and-results-builder.html)
- [Framing Cross Section Analyser and REX](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/12/security-framing-cross-section-analyser-and-rex.html)
- [Framing Cross Section Analyser and REX in Revit 2015](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/03/framing-cross-section-analyser-and-rex-in-revit-2015.html)
- [REX Add-In Development and Migration](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/rex-app-development-and-migration.html)
- [REX SDK FreezeDrawing Sample](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/10/au-revit-20171-and-rex-freezedrawing.html#5)